# to copy column from one table to another in psql

Tags: postgresql

I want to copy column `User_id` from `public."firstapp_offer_Vendor"` to table `firstapp_bid` on the basis of `oid`, i.e. if `oid` in `firstapp_offer_Vendor` is equal to `firstapp_bid.offer_id` then `user_id` should be copied to `vendor_id`.

Here are my two tables:

Table `firstapp_bid`:

```
id   Bid  offer_id vendor_id        
1   "123"   1       null
2   "123"   6       null
3   "123"   13      null
4   "120"   13      null
5   "140"   14      null
6   "130"   14      null
7   "140"   14      null
8   "150"   14      null
9   "123"   15      null
10  "123"   16      null
11  "120"   16      null
```

Table `first_app_offer_vendor`:

```
id oid user_id
1   1   3
12  6   2
26  13  3
27  13  4
28  14  2
29  14  4
30  14  6
31  14  7
32  15  7
33  16  6
34  16  7
```

The output table should be:

```
id   Bid  offer_id vendor_id        
1   "123"   1       3
2   "123"   6       2
3   "123"   13      3
4   "120"   13      4
5   "140"   14      2
6   "130"   14      4
7   "140"   14      6
8   "150"   14      7
9   "123"   15      7
10  "123"   16      6
11  "120"   16      7
```

I tried implementing that using

```
INSERT INTO firstapp_bid 
(
   vendor_id
) 
SELECT 
   user_id 
FROM 
   public."firstapp_offer_Vendor" 
WHERE
   public."firstapp_offer_Vendor".oid = public."firstapp_bid.offer_id
```

but it gives me the wrong output.

Comment: Can you provide the table DDL and the wrong output ?

Comment: in this, these two tables are formed through Django model migration.In firstapp_offer_vendor table id is the primary key ,user is is a foreign key linked to user table and in firstapp_bid table id is the primary key and and offer id is the foreign key link to  firstapp_offer_vendor table offerid field. Wrong O/P is :                                            id    bid   ofr id user id
1 123 1 3
38 125 1 3

In this I want to enter 2 different userid for similar offer id.Example userid should be 2 & 3 for offer id 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an insert here, as this is about adding new rows. You want rather to make an update. Something like

```
create table a(id int, v varchar(10));
create table b(id int, v varchar(10));

insert into a
select 1, 'a'
union all
select 2, 'b';

insert into b
select 1, null
union 
select 2, null;


update b set v = a.v
from a where a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: I tried the same through update query given by you but there is 1 issue in this.I have 4 entries with same offer_id but different user_id ,after updating all user_ids are updated by same user_id for 1 offer_id.for example there are 4 entries with offer_id 14 and user_id 2,4,6,7 but after updating user_id for 4 entries contains 2,2,2,2.Please help

Comment: So you're apparently missing something in this structure. Currently the sql is not able to distinguish one first_app_offer_vendor row from another looking only at `oid` column. like here

```id oid user_id
26  13  3
27  13  4
```

so it does not know which `user_id` you really want. So you either would need to make sure that these `offer_id`/`oid` are unique or you may need to provide a more straight relation between these tables with foreign key, for example.

Comment: Or, if it does not matter to you to which row from `firstapp_bid` which `user_id` will be matched as long as `offer_id` is right, you could try to update them somehow, but it will be rather complex and, at the updated vendors will be random (in ranges of specific offer).

Comment: for this case offer id cannot be unique and i'm still not able to figure out how to implement the same .Please help

Comment: So it seems like a design issue. What do you want to achieve with that? Are these structures something what already exists, or you are creating that, so you could modify architecture a little bit? And from where come rows in both tables?

Comment: i create a unique id in both tables and on the basis updated firstapp_bid table.Thanks for your help